# Jenkins build status icons are not showing in github

Tags: jenkins, github

I used to see the green ticks or the red X next to the commits on github. I updated the plugins yesterday and I do not see them anymore. I have not made any configuration changes. Is it because of the new version of the github plugin for jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution to my problem. Here are the steps to solve the problem:

1. Go to your github user settings (https://github.com/settings/profile)
2. Select Developer settings > Personal access tokens > Generate new token
3. **Token description**: add a description (e.g. Jenkins github plugin)
4. From **Select scopes** select all the options from **repo**.
5. Click on **Generate token** and a token will be generated, copy the token.
6. Now go to Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global credentials (unrestricted) > Add Credentials
7. **Kind**: Secret text
8. **Scope**: Global
9. **Secret**: Paste the token generated in github
10. **Id**: Leave it empty
11. **Description**: Add a description (e.g. Github Secret text) and click ok
12. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > GitHub > GitHub Servers
13. Add GitHub server
14. **Name**: Add a name
15. **API URL**: https://api.github.com
16. **Credentials**: select **Github Secret text** that you created previously
17. Check **Manage hooks**.
18. If Test connection is successful then you will be able to see the build status icons by your github commits or branches.

Comment: I followed the steps and tested the connection. it echos "Credentials verified for user yowyow, rate limit: 4998" but sadly the icons won't appear against the commits. Got something like this in the Jenkins logs. `com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform getSelectedProtocol
INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few [recent issues around Status with the GitHub plugin for Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54249?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20github-plugin%20AND%20text%20%7E%20status%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC).

[JENKINS-53824](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53824), for instance, mentions:

> No status was set on the commit. After following most of the suggested workarounds on the web (Manual Repo, Manual SHA etc) it still showed nothing.
>
> From looking at the code of the plugin and the logs of AnyRepo, it seemed that the step did not find the correct server.
>
> Going to the Configuration of Jenkins and looking at the configuration for GitHub. It seems that the GitHub Server config section now also allows enterprise servers as well but there is still the GitHub Enterprise section (where my server was listed).
>
> **After some playing, I found that when I add the GHE server to the GitHub Server section as well, the commit status is working as expected**.

Comment: I guess this feature is only available for "GitHub Enterprise" customers (those who pay) then.

Comment: @BentCoder I suspect so, yes.

Comment: GitHub Enterprise API endpoint seems [customer specific](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.16/v3/enterprise-admin/) so yes sadly it is not for me anymore. Anyway, I shall move on.